# Updating your question to add a solution

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, behavior

Occasionally, I see people who have updated their question, to add the solution that they ended up using. In some cases, this edit is a summarized version of whatever is the top voted (or accepted) answer.

Does the SE community have consensus about whether this is good or bad practice? Personally, I think that it's beneficial because the solution will be easiest to find for the reader. On the other hand, it's disadvantageous to the person who provided this answer, since they won't get as many upvotes when people don't have to scroll down to see their post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is bad practice.  Although, I must admit that I have never seen it on the SE sites that I visit.

Questions should not contain answers.  It defies the logic of the system as described in the help pages.  You cannot upvote a good answer if it is in the question.

I would suggest that answers that have been edited into a question should be rolled back.  Remove the answer.

Comment: I see, that sounds logical. Lemme just edit my post to add th-- wait, no.

Comment: @LeeWhite I tend to add a comment along the lines of "Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)" (with the link modified to point to the correct site of course) **if** the user has clearly something to add to one of the other answers, and then rollback as appropriate.

Answer (score 6):

Adding summarized version of the answers in the question doesn't only harm the answerers, but also isn't necessary, because if the problem is not too localized, any person will have to optimize and rethink the given solutions for their purposes - and it doesn't really matter that for OP it works this exactly this and that ways.

Also, the solution is not the part of the question - the question does *ask*, but not *answer*. If the OP has their *own* solution, they can post it as separate answer, but of course not go and embed it in the question.